# Amazon EC2: No supported authentication methods available

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I was testing some stuff in my Amazon EC2 instance and I have deleted `authorized_keys` from `.ssh` folder. I had public and private keys generated, but now I can't start a sessios, Putty shows that message:

```
No supported authentication methods available
```

I have tried to connect by `ssh ec2-user@ip` but I get `Permission denied (publickey)`. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Restore your deleted credentials to the .ssh folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options:

1. Start a new instance, you can move your data by detaching the EBS volume.
2. Attempt to restore the .ssh file. This is somewhat involved, but can be done. Stop your instance. Detach the volume, attach to new instance. Mount the volume inside the new instance and fix the missing file. Make sure permissions are correct too. Unmount detach volume and reattach to original instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to your instance using SSH and get any of the following errors, Host key not found in [directory], Permission denied (publickey), or Authentication failed, permission denied, verify that you are connecting with the appropriate user name for your AMI and that you have specified the proper private key (.pem) file for your instance. For MindTerm clients, enter the user name in the User name box in the Connect To Your Instance window.

The appropriate user names are as follows:

For an Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
For a RHEL5 AMI, the user name is either root or ec2-user.
For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
For a Fedora AMI, the user name is either fedora or ec2-user.
For SUSE Linux, the user name is either root or ec2-user.
Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI provider.

Link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingPuTTY